# Focus-visible on mouse hover, but first time only

Tags: css, css-selectors, hover, pseudo-class

I'm confused on the heuristic behaviour of the CSS pseudo class `:focus-visible`.

In our application, we have dropdowns in some places. I noticed that when I refresh the page, the `:focus:focus-visible` is applied to a freshly opened dropdown (its items), on mouse hover.

But once I click basically any button in the application, for example just reopening the dropdown, the focus-visible pseudo does not apply anymore.

See video:
[image]

I've currently changed the outline color to be more subtle, because this really seems like unintended behaviour to me, but I do not want to lose the outline when a user uses a keyboard to navigate.

Can someone explain me what's going on with the mouse hover behaviour?

Answer (score -1):

Whenever you click on an element, browsers use an internal heuristic to determine whether they should display a default focus indicator. This is why in Chrome tabbing to a  shows a focus ring, but clicking it with a mouse does not.
Actually :focus-visible is for keyboard not for mouse.
Read this article for more clarification.
[Link](https://blog.chromium.org/2020/09/giving-users-and-developers-more.html)

Comment: as you can see I'm only using mouse hover. So if it is like you said, only on keyboard input, why is it showing on mouse hover after a refresh?

Comment: That is only default focus indicator. A default browser behavior when use :focus-visible. If you want hover , try using :hover css property.